# При нажатии на notification открыть папку

Tags: android

Здраствуйте у меня есть notification и при нажатии на него хотелс бы штоб открывалась папка но этого не происходит

```
    public void showNotification(boolean p) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folder")));
         pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,0);
         r = getResources();
        notification = PutDatainsideNoti(p);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте `Intent` вот так собрать (т.е. замените строку)

> pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Папка/"), 0);

на:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Папка/");
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: можете пожалуста объяснить , я понял из вашего атвета што в  PendingIntent надо запустить intent

Comment: @DavidKern, см. обновлённый ответ

Comment: я это и сделал но про нажатии на notification ничего не происходит

Comment: умена есть папка в катораю сохраняются изображения и выводится notification при нажатии на notification надо штоб открывалась папка куда была сохранина картинка

Comment: @DavidKern, а вы указали, что этот интент notification должен использовать? Т.е. вызвали `.setContentIntent(intent)` на `notification`?

Comment: да я добали и добавил полняю версию кода

Comment: @DavidKern и в `PutDatainsideNoti(boolean p)` вы передаёте `true`? Может поможет добавление разрешений на чтение файлов в манифесте, хотя врятли. И вы проверяли не из уведомления запуск `Intent` с открытие папки?

Comment: я проверял интент на открытие gallery в телефоне работал

Comment: @DavidKern,, других идей у меня нет.

Comment: огромное спасибо за помаш :) я думаю надо воспользоваться setDataAndType