# Ошибка при работе с нажатием на Notification android

Tags: android

Я только начал работать с `notification`, и у меня возник один вопрос который касается создания самого уведомления. Для начала, что-бы создать уведомление, во всех инструкциях пишут что нужно написать такую строку:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageShow.class);
```

после нескольких попыток что-то поменять, я понял что эта строка отвечает за переход на определенное активити, при нажатии на уведомление. Я хочу создать это уведомление для информирования пользователя о том что был загружен файл, и при нажатии на само уведомление я хочу либо открывать загруженный файл, либо открывать папку "Загрузки". Я нашел такой вопрос - [При нажатии на notification открыть папку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472310/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-notification-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83). Все сделал как было написано в ответе, но у меня выскочила ошибка:

```
E: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.developer_4.test_login, PID: 9000
    android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///Download exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

вот как я делаю переход в определенную папку:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Не могу понять в чем может быть ошибка, и буду рад если вы мне поможете.

Comment: `File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);` - Вы, наверное, эту папку имели в ввиду. Только я сомневаюсь, что на любом устройстве найдётся приложение, способное такой интент обработать.

Comment: А как же мне перейти в папку загрузок, или  может открывать файл? Как вы считаете что будет удобнее? Просто я не уверен что вывод просто уведомления без клика на него будет кому-то интересен)

Comment: Видимо вам нужен FileProvider: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/3212712