# Как открыть файл из notification android studio?

Tags: android, android-notification

У меня в приложении есть функция которая позволяет загружать файлы с сервера, файл который загружен сохраняется в папке `Downloads`. Я хочу сделать всплывающее уведомление, при нажатии на которое я смогу открыть загруженный файл. То есть по логике я должен получить доступ к папке и к файлу, и дальше его открыть. Я пробовал открывать папку при нажатии на уведомление, но мои попытки не увенчались успехом. Если никак нельзя реализовать то что я пытаюсь сделать, то возникает закономерный вопрос - имеет ли смысл вообще создание уведомления при загрузке. Вот например есть такой мобильный браузер Google Chrome, в котором при загрузке файла всплывает `SnackBar` где есть кнопка открыть при нажатии на которую вы можете открыть только-что загруженный документ. Буду очень благодарен если поможете мне с решением данной проблемы.

Comment: По идее надо просто нужный интент прицепить к нажатию на уведомление. Типа так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6381479/3212712 Только интент в PendingIntent обернуть

Comment: ну я пробовал прилепить к нажатию нужный интент, но была ошибка - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/874987/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-notification-android

Comment: Видимо вам нужен FileProvider: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, с каждый вашим комментарием я понимаю что опять пытаюсь затронуть какую-то довольно непонятную для себя тему)) а разве обычным интентом никак нельзя открыть документ?

Comment: Необязательно понимать) Можно просто скопировать код и оно заработает) Обычным интентом можно, но это будет работать не везде и не всегда, обычно от уровня ОС зависит. На API<21 может и просто можно, но если хотите чтобы везде работало - надо извращаться

Comment: то есть насколько я понял по тем вопросами что вы мне кинули, мне нужно использовать `FileProvider` и нужный интент?

Comment: Да, всё верно. Ну и ссылка на файл также должна быть правильной. Но тут либо глубоко разобраться надо куда и как он пишется или методом перебора выяснять)

Comment: а еще вопрос - по сайту вопрос на мете задавать нужно? а то у меня есть несколько вопросов)

Comment: и кстати что означает ссылка на файл - путь или название?

Comment: Да, вопросы по работе сайта - это на мету) Под ссылкой да, имею в виду путь к файлу на девайсе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я долго размышлял над тем как реализовать тот механизм который я хочу видеть в своем приложение, то есть при нажатии на уведомление я хотел что-бы у меня открывался загруженный файл, при нажатии на уведомление. С объяснений в коментариях я понял что такой функционал реализовать вероятнее всего не получится, поэтому я сделал так, чтобы я смог открыть хотя бы папку загрузок. Вот какое у меня получилось уведомление:

```
private void notification(String name) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        Uri pathUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + "/Download/");
        intent.setDataAndType(pathUri, "file/*");

        final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);


        Notification n = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(name)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setProgress(0, 0, false)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_get_app_black_24dp)
                .setAutoCancel(true).build();

        n.ledARGB = Color.RED;
        n.ledOffMS = 0;
        n.ledOnMS = 1;
        n.flags = n.flags | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

        n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Objects.requireNonNull(notificationManager).notify(0, n);
    }
```

надеюсь кому-то поможет мой способ. Удачи:)